# Swift 5 split string at integer index

Tags: swift, string, swift5

It used to be you could use substring to get a portion of a string. That has been deprecated in favor on string index. But I can't seem to make a string index out of integers.

```
var str = "hellooo"
let newindex = str.index(after: 3)
str = str[newindex...str.endIndex]
```

No matter what the string is, I want the second 3 characters. So and str would contain "loo". How can I do this?

Comment: shoot I realized my example didn't have enough characters, but I want the prefix with an offset I guess.

Comment: thanks! .drop was it

Answer (score 1):

Drop the first three characters and the get the remaining first three characters

```
let str = "helloo"
let secondThreeCharacters = String(str.dropFirst(3).prefix(3))
```

You might add some code to handle the case if there are less than 6 characters in the string